# Quick fix - schematron

Tags: schematron

I wrote a quickfix to insert a space between digit and string for example: 15MHz,20Hz

**Schematron**

```
<sch:pattern>
    <sch:title>quick-fix</sch:title>
    <sch:rule context="//text()">
      
        <sch:report
            test="matches(.,'(\d+)MHz') or matches(.,'(\d+)Hz')"
            sqf:fix="groupfix" role="warning">Insert a space</sch:report>
        
        <sqf:group id="groupfix">
            
            
            <sqf:fix id="MHz-fix" use-when="contains(current(), 'MHz')">
                <sqf:description>
                    <sqf:title>Insert space before MHz
                    </sqf:title>
                </sqf:description>
                <sqf:replace>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\d+)MHz">
                        <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"
                        /><xsl:value-of select="' MHz'"
                        /></xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."
                        /></xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </sqf:replace>
            </sqf:fix>
            
            
            <sqf:fix id="Hz-fix" use-when="contains(current(), 'Hz')">
                <sqf:description>
                    <sqf:title>Insert space before Hz
                    </sqf:title>
                </sqf:description>
                <sqf:replace>
                    <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="(\d+)Hz">
                        <xsl:matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="regex-group(1)"
                        /><xsl:value-of select="' Hz'"
                        /></xsl:matching-substring>
                        <xsl:non-matching-substring><xsl:value-of select="."
                        /></xsl:non-matching-substring>
                    </xsl:analyze-string>
                </sqf:replace>
            </sqf:fix>

        </sqf:group>
    </sch:rule>
</sch:pattern>
```

**xml**

```
<topic>
<p>15MHz</p>
</topic>
```

I am able to insert the space before MHz but the quick fix displays two options "Insert space before MHz" and "Insert space before Hz". I want only "Insert space before MHz" to be displayed.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In stead of this:

```xml
<sqf:fix id="Hz-fix" use-when="contains(current(), 'Hz')">
```

do this:

```xml
<sqf:fix id="Hz-fix" use-when="matches(current(), '(\d+)Hz')">
```

- Use in `use-when` also the `matches` function which checks for the given pattern.
- Optional:

  - you can replace `current()` with `.` to save code.
  - In Oxygen you can use `<sqf:stringReplace regex="(\d+)Hz" select="'$1 Hz'"/>` instead of the complex `<xsl:analyze-string>`.